# Open office Excel content addin with new sheet

Tags: office-js

I've created an Office Excel Content Add-in. Its working is working fine but when it opens, the add-in hides the current sheet's content.

I wanted to open it on a new sheet. I've searched through the [Excel JavaScript API](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/worksheet) but I unable to find a solution.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. [Content Office Add-ins](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/design/content-add-ins) will always be inserted into the active view (doc, sheet, slide, etc.). Much like inserting an image, where it is inserted and positioned is entirely up to the user.